# Place the image at random x,y of the screen and make the image invisible after certain peroid in android

Tags: android, image, random, coordinates

I need to create an image at random places. After few seconds it has to be disappeared. After the first image get disappeared the second image has to come. I used the following code to place the image at random coordinates and use a handler to make it invisible after few seconds. I used for loop to create some number of images. All the images comes and goes at the same time. I think the for loop is the problem. I couldn't find a solution for that. Any help is appreciated.

```
     ImageView iv=null;
     RelativeLayout rl=null;
     Random rand= new Random();
     int min=10, max=100;
     int randomNum;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){

    randomNum = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    Log.d("RandomNum",Integer.toString(randomNum));
    Log.d("i value",Integer.toString(i));
    iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 40);
    params.leftMargin = 50+randomNum;
    params.topMargin = 60+randomNum;
    rl.addView(iv, params);
    timerDelayRemoveView(500, iv);

}
    }


    public void timerDelayRemoveView(long time, final ImageView iv){
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {           
            public void run() {                
                iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);         
            }
            },  time); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement a `timerDelayAddView` (like you delayed `timerDelayRemoveView`) where you specify an image-dependent delay (e.g. `2000 * i`) before you call `addView`.

Comment: Thanks Howard. I replaced the code as you said. But even the app didn't run. I couldn't found anything on the emulator.